# How to get clean data objects from mongoose to merge with other objects in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using express with typescript.
On the login function I get the googleId from the user DB document, I get the shift created by the google id (author) and also need to set a new key value (isAuthenticated: true).

All these objects needs to be merged into the API response.
The code:

```
import ShiftModel from '../../models/Shift.model';
userRouter.get('/get-user', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const { googleId }: any = req.user;
    const shift = await ShiftModel.findOne({ requiredByUserId: googleId });


    // const response = Object.assign({} , req.user, shift, { isAuthenticated: true });
    let response = {
      ...req.user,
      ...shift,
      ...{ isAuthenticated: true }
    }
    console.log(response);
    

    res.status(200).json(req.user);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

What I tried:

1. I tried object.assign:

```
const response = Object.assign({} , req.user, shift, { isAuthenticated: true });
```

2. Spread operator

```
let response = {
      ...req.user,
      ...shift,
      ...{ isAuthenticated: true }
    }
```

I get e response with alot of symbold like:

```
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    activePaths: StateMachine { paths: [Object], states: [Object] },
    skipId: true
  },
  '$isNew': false,
  _doc: {
    _id: new ObjectId("6501bc166242e72ea25448f3"),
    days: [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'thursday', 'friday' ],
    available: true,
    shiftPattern: 'days',
    startHour: '08:00',
    endHour: '17:30',
    requiredByUserId: '115426204517705247377',
    dateCreated: 2023-09-13T13:39:57.561Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  isAuthenticated: true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I assume you are using Mongoose to find and store data in a MongoDB database. Before you merge your `shift` result into your final response object, you should call [`.toObject()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.toObject()) or [`.toJSON()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.toJSON()) on it, possibly with further options depending on your needs.

The reason why this is necessary is because Mongoose uses its own model class to store the results, including a lot of internal state and metadata (as you see in your example code, e.g. `$__` or `$isNew`). To get a simple and clean object that you are looking for, you would have to call one of the two mentioned instance methods (see the links above) of your `shift` document like so:

```
let shift = await ShiftModel.findOne({ requiredByUserId: googleId });

shift = shift.toJSON(); // or shift.toObject();
```

Alternatively, the data you are interested in (the actual data of your document) is stored under `shift._doc`, so you could just do

```
let response = {
  ...req.user,
  ...shift._doc,
  ...{ isAuthenticated: true }
}
```

as well, while using the approach with [`.toObject()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.toObject()) or [`.toJSON()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.toJSON()) would probably be the better way.